# Collapsible div as a row element

Tags: html

I am trying to prepare a simple mark sheet [as an example to demonstrate my requirement]. Am planning to have a collapsible div which will render all the mark details once it is expanded.

```
<div class="well">
  <table class="table table-bordered" 
         style="background:#fff; margin-bottom:10px;">
    <tbody>  
      <tr class="inverse">
        <th> ID</th>
        <th colspan="2"> Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>
          <a  class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#ID_1" 
              aria-expanded="false"  >
              Hide/Unhide
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">    
          <div class="collapse" id="ID_1">
            <div class="well">
              <table  class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="background:#fff; margin-bottom:10px;">
                <thead>                
                   <tr class="inverse">
                      <th>Subject</th>
                      <th>Mark</th>
                   </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>                
                  <tr>
                    <td>Physics </td>
                    <td>100</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>    
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="inverse">
        <th> ID</th>
        <th colspan="2"> Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>PQR</td>
        <td>
          <a  class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#ID_2" 
              aria-expanded="false"    >
              Hide/Unhide
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">    
          <div class="collapse" id="ID_2">
            <div class="well">
              <table  class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="background:#fff; margin-bottom:10px;">
                <thead>                
                   <tr class="inverse">
                      <th>Subject</th>
                      <th>Mark</th>
                   </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>                
                  <tr>
                    <td>Chemistry</td>
                    <td>100</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>    
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soumyazyx/BVmUL/1508/)

But in this approach, when a section is not expanded, the row which encloses the collapsible div appears like a blank row in the table - which is quite misleading.

I am sure this is not the best way to render this sort of details.Would like to know what are the alternate UI options to render these details.

Comment: Point taken.Added the code.

Comment: You can make padding 0 for the cell <td colspan="3" style="padding:0;">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
td[colspan="3"] {
  padding: 0;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b16m0frp/)